# getClass().getResource() with Java Web Start

Tags: java, java-web-start

When I use **getClass().getResource(ACCEPT_PNG)** to load an ImageIcon, it works well on my local compute.
When my class is embeded with its ressource in a JAR, for a Java Web Start application, the ressource can't be found, and the same code returns null...

Any idea?

```
   /** Path to a PNG ressource. */
   private static final String ACCEPT_PNG = "accept.png";

   private static ImageIcon acceptPngIcon = null;

   private ImageIcon getAcceptPngIcon() {
      if (acceptPngIcon == null) {
         acceptPngIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(ACCEPT_PNG));
      }
      return acceptPngIcon;
   }
```

Comment: Locally, what directory do you have the PNG in? In the JAR where do you put it?

Comment: 1) What is the content of the JNLP file? 2) Which jar is supposed to contain the image?  3) What is the dump of the contents of that Jar?  Without this information, I can only guess, & I don't like guessing.

Comment: From the question, it sounds like you havent tried reading the resource from a jar file without WebStart. I suggest trying that if you haven't. (I also suggest avoiding mutable statics.)

Comment: since accept.png isn't proceeded by a slash, it is assumed to be where the class that this code is. If this is not the case, and instead the accept.png is at the root of the class path, prepend a slash.

Comment: For posterity: I had this problem tonight... It took me forever to realize that on a local machine there is no difference between `.png` and `.PNG`, but when you load with Java Web Start, URLs are case-sensitive. So, make sure you check that you enter your resources in -exactly-, case and all.

Comment: Any resolution on this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved it by following the approach in Oracle's Java Web Start [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/retrievingResources.html): use the class loader to retrieve the resource instead of the class itself:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(ACCEPT_PNG); 
    // works both locally and via Web Start
getClass().getResource(ACCEPT_PNG); 
    // only works locally; returns null for any path via Web Start
```